# What is the codepoint of the RIGHT HALF CIRCLE in Unicode?

Tags: fonts, shapes, unicode, character-design

There are 9 characters are found with **Left Half Circle** in Unicode:

Left Half Circle

Left Half Circle With Dot

Left Half Circle With Four Dots

Left Half Circle With Three Dots

Left Half Circle With Two Dots

◖
Left Half Black Circle

⨭
Plus Sign In Left Half Circle

⨴
Multiplication Sign In Left Half Circle

◐
Circle with Left Half Black

Only 4 unicode characters are found with **Right Half Circle**:

◗
Right Half Black Circle

⨮
Plus Sign In Right Half Circle

⨵
Multiplication Sign In Right Half Circle

◑
Circle with Right Half Black

**Question**: How to display Right Half Circle (the right part of ⨮) in plain text without latex?

Comment: "the right part of ⨮" -- isn't what you have the right part?

Comment: @Zach Saucler, yes, right half circle is the counterpart of [], if your font can display this character, namely, ⨮ without +.